# How to use Tinkerpop with actors

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, thread-local, tinkerpop

I would like to know if I can use tinkerpop within Akka Futures, so far when I commit my changes to the graph they don't get persisted. 
I understand tinkerpop is a thread-local library which mean I'd need to set my thread again within the future `ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(thread)`

I tried the following method without success :

```
def test[T](graphChanges: => T): T = {
    val thread = ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.get
    try graphChanges finally {
      ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(thread)
      GraphPool.get("partitioned").commit
    }
}

// collect tinkerpop frames
test {
  future {
  // add changes to my tinkerpop frames
  }
}
```

I would like to have on Tinkerpop thread per play.mvc.Http.Context

Here is a sample project with what I want to achieve : https://github.com/D-Roch/tinkerpop-play

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The problem

The problem is, that Tinkerpop works thread local. So your changes are only committed to the current thread. When creating Scala futures, you let the environment choose, in which thread the future will be executed. And the environment doesn't know better, so it chooses the wrong thread.

The problem is similar for Akka futures.

### In which thread does a future run?

When creating a future, you are creating it with two parameters:

1. The block that should be executed
2. The [Execution Context](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext) that should execute the block

The second parameter is usually given as an implicit parameter. But you can override the default.

### Solution

When creating futures dealing with Tinkerpop, use an execution context that runs every block in the same thread.

Example:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

implicit val ec=ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor)

future { 
    println(Thread.currentThread); 
    future {
        println(Thread.currentThread)
    }  
}
```

This code prints out the same thread id twice on the console (tested with Java 7 and Scala 2.10.2.

*Attention:* Using such a small thread pool can easily lead to dead locks or starvation. Use it only for your Tinkerpop interaction.

You can either provide a special method tinkerpopFuture that takes a block as an parameter and returns a future that will run in the tinkerpop thread. Or you can create a special actor which encapsulates all tinkerpop interactions (and runs them with the special tinkerpop exection context).

### Literature

- You can see some example code for creating an execution context [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html).
- Documentation for [Akka Futures and execution contexts](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/futures.html)

Comment: Thank you for your input, it makes sense but I don't really know how to proceed, should I override the exec context after this future : https://github.com/D-Roch/tinkerpop-play/blob/master/app/models/Base.scala#L80

Comment: You use the method scala.concurrent.future, which takes an implicit second parameter of type "ExecutionContext". In your case it will take the default ExecutionContext from import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global. You can override this by providing an "implicit val tinkerpopCtx : ExecutionContext = ..." with your single thread execution context. For more details about implicit parameters see http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/114

Comment: Thanks, I understand how implicit vars work but what would I pass instead to override the ExecutionContext ?

Comment: You just use an ExecutionContext that will run everything in one thread. You can easily create one using java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService, e.g. ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(ExecutorService.newSingleThreadExecutor). I have to try the correct syntax and will then add an example in the answer above.

Comment: impressive, thank you for your explaining I wasn't expecting the answer to be so easy ;-) I have done some tests and I get very good results but it's not perfect : http://pastebin.com/MsX4R1kE as you can see line 456 I get one failed insert but maybe it's just orientdb ?

Comment: Looks good! Regarding the one failed insert, I think you have to add more logging. Based on given data I have no idea why it has failed.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't look like anything specific to Tinkerpop, it looks like a common error made with using Futures.  Just consider this fragment:

```
try graphChanges finally { ... }
```

It looks fine by itself, but I can also see that `graphChanges` here is creating a future. So...

- `graphChanges` initiates a Future, returning instantly
- the `try` block completes and the `finally` block is executed
- At some point immediately before this, or after, or maybe in parallel, but almost certainly on another thread, the `Future` is executed

My advice would be to move the asynchronous logic inside `test`, so that you can be sure of the correct thread-affinity and ensure that any calls are correctly flagged as `blocking`.  Like this:

```
def test[T](graphChanges: => T): Future[T] = future {
  blocking {
    val tlocal = ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE
    val dbrecord = tlocal.get

    try graphChanges finally {
      tlocal.set(dbrecord)
      GraphPool.get("partitioned").commit
    }
  }
}

// collect tinkerpop frames
test {
  // add changes to my tinkerpop frames
}
```